# SQL Query to find rows based on descriptions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT sequence 
from prices 
WHERE match_description <> '' 
  AND 'SIP Trunk: 123456 (1 Channel)' LIKE CONCAT(match_description, '%') 
ORDER BY length(match_description) desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

I have rows that have a `match_description` of:

```
SIP Trunk (1 Channel)
SIP Trunk (2 Channels)
SIP Trunk (3 Channels)
```

etc...

when running the above query, the string looks like `SIP Trunk: 123456 (x Channels)`

how can i match these with my rows correctly?

bearing in mind, the query i have works with other strings so i cannot change it too much.

for example, other queries that run are like:

```
SELECT sequence from prices WHERE match_description <> '' AND 'Seat 200' LIKE CONCAT(match_description, '%') ORDER BY length(match_description) desc LIMIT 1;
```

this will match a row with `match_description` of `Seat`

the queries are run when i upload a CSV file. this includes product names that are supplied to me so they are uploaded as they are sent to me.

some example rows would be:

```
Seat 200
Seat 201
Seat 202
Call Queue 200
Call Group 201
Geographic Number 01234 567890
SIP Trunk: 123456 (2 Channels)
SIP Trunk: 654321 (5 Channels)
```

So, using my query, I am able to match all except for the last two.

for the ones I can match, i have the following in `match_description` in my table:

```
Seat
Seat
Seat
Call Queue
Call Group
Geographic Number
```

i am just unsure how to match these? (the 123456 and 654321 are different for each product)

```
SIP Trunk: 123456 (2 Channels)
SIP Trunk: 654321 (5 Channels)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. It sounds like you want the functionality of `like` to change, based on the content of the pattern.  That is not how SQL works.  You need to bring in the pattern that you want to match.

Comment: can you post the incorrect rows matched?

Comment: Do you need to match just SIP Trunk:  (x Channel) or SIP Trunk:  (x Channel) first and then then number 123456. You can just ignore 123456 part by doing some string operations in query or in your csv if you don't need it.

Comment: the uploaded file will be `SIP Trunk: 123456 (x Channels)` but in my database, i will not have these different numbers stored. all i have is a products table that has a product for each number of channels -  `SIP Trunk: (x Channels)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the first 11 characters to `SIP Trunk:`, then the last 9/ 10 characters to `channel)` or `channels)` then that way, if your match_description is of the form: `SIP Trunk: yyyyyy (x Channels)` it will pick it up. The `MID` statements will make sure that `x` and `yyyyyy` are integers and the opening bracket is there.

Also, thanks to @dwjv who points out you won't be able to index on the match_description column.

```
SELECT 
    sequence 
FROM 
    prices 
WHERE 
    match_description <> '' 
AND 
    LEFT(match_description, 11) = 'SIP Trunk: '
AND
    (RIGHT(match_description, 9) = ' channel)' OR
     RIGHT(match_description, 10) = ' channels)')
AND
    MID(match_description, 12,6) REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
AND
    MID(match_description, 18,3) = ' ( '
AND
    MID(match_description, 20,1) REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
ORDER BY 
    length(match_description) desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: probably enough, but you could also add in `AND MID(match_description, 12,1) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Comment: Good shout, put in a little `REGEXP` to check it parses as an integer.

Comment: Nice :-). Probably worth pointing out this won't be able to use any indexes on the match_description column though.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT sequence 
from prices 
WHERE match_description <> '' 
  AND match_description LIKE  '%SIP Trunk: 123456 (% Channel%)%'
ORDER BY length(match_description) desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the string to match to your match_description
For example you can encode SIP Trunk 12345(x Channel) to SIP Trunk (x Channel) 12345

This way your values will match with string.

```
SIP Trunk (1 Channel)
SIP Trunk (2 Channels)
SIP Trunk (3 Channels)
```

For encoding purpose you may use case statement on the variable that gives you specific type of string.

Do you need to match just SIP Trunk: (x Channel) or SIP Trunk: (x Channel) first and then number 123456. You can just ignore 123456 part by doing some string operations in query or in your csv if you don't need it.